# Why “de + infinitive” instead of “à + -ant" in “finissez de mourir”?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, prépositions, mode-grammatical

In a French translation of [*The Bonfire of the Vanities*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bonfire_of_the_Vanities), the English news headline "Please Finish Dying Before X Arrives" was translated

> Finissez gentiment de mourir avant que X n'arrive.

I'm confused by the construction *finissez **de** mourir*… A literal translation from English might be *finissez à  mourant*, using an "ing" construction. What is the meaning/context of the French "de" + infinitive construction?

Comment: By the way, spelling: *finir* (only one `n`) → *finissez* (nous …issons, vous …issez, ils …issent), *à* (preposition). And were there really capitals in the translation? They would normally not be used in news headlines in French.

Comment: Gilles: Thank you for the correction, and your answer below. As for the headline, in my version, it was all "capitals." But this is a French translation of a novel talking about a "sensational" headline in either English or French.

Comment: Et n'aurait-on pas pu traduire par _S'il vous plaît arrêtez d'être mourant avant que X arrive_ ? Je pose la question, car je connais mal l'anglais.

Comment: @Istao : *Finish Dying* veut bien dire « finir de mourir », alors qu'« arrêter d'être mourant » peut vouloir dire guérir (en plus de pas sonner très très naturel en français…)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it comes down to the fact that the French present participle is a very poor equivalent to the English gerund.

In particular in English, constructions using a [Non-finite verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_verb) as an object or a subject will frequently use a gerund ("walking is slower than running"). In French such constructions will never use a present participle (at least I can't think of examples off the top of my head. I'm fairly sure the present participle cannot be used as if it were a noun), but normally use the infinitive (*Marcher est moins rapide que courir*) or a nominalisation (*La marche est moins rapide que la course*).

Regarding the part where you ask about de+infinitive, this is but the most common way to connect an infinitive serving as a verbal complement to its head. In many cases (as here), the conjugated verb expresses a [grammatical aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) (here a cessative or terminative aspect). The other constructions are the direct verb+infinitive construction (*aimer*, *faire* and *pouvoir* work this way) and verb+à+infinitive (*réussir*, *parvenir* are examples of this one). A few verbs allow other prepositions in corner cases, like *partir* and *suffire*, which sometime construct an infinitive with *pour*.

As with the English [catenative verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb), you ahve to know which verb uses which construction, although there is some variation (Grevisse's *Le Bon usage* spends nearly 15 pages discussing it): *continuer* and *commencer* are often built with *à* instead of *de* in literary style, for example.

Comment: « On marche moins vite que l'on ne court » me vient aussi à l'esprit…

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's more to it than the somewhat arbitrary fact that the verb *finir* is constructed with the preposition *de* followed by an infinitive (a verb after the preposition *de* is always in the infinitive mood). *Finir de mourir*, *achever de mourir*, *terminer de mourir* (rare, *terminer* is normally only followed by a noun).

<s>*À mourant*</s> (note the accent on the preposition *à*, to distinguish it from *il a* from the verb *avoir*) is not valid French. The preposition *à* is also always followed by an infinitive: *commencer à mourir*, *se préparer à mourir*.

There is no grammatical analogue in French of the English (or Latin) [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_in_English). To turn a verb into a noun, one usually uses the infinitive.
*Mourir est inévitable* = Dying (or: to die) is unavoidable.

Comment: The construction seems to be, "finish of dying," where "de" is a so-called "adverb of quantity."